# How to configure a SSL certificate to be used by Kubernetes with Google Cloud?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, gcloud

I am trying to send my app to a Google Cloud Cluster using the `kubectl` command behind a corporative proxy that needs a certificate ".crt" file to be used when doing HTTPS requests.

I already ran the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials...` command and it also asked for a certificate. I followed the given instructions by Google and I configured my certificate file without any issue and it worked.

But when I try the `kubectl get pods` I am getting the following message:

```
"Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
```

How can I configure my certificate file to be used by the kubectl command?

I did a search about this subject but I found too difficult steps. Could I just run something like this:

```
kubectl --set_ca_file /path/to/my/cert
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The short answer up to what I know is no.

here[1] you can see the step by step of how to get this done in the easiest way I found so far, is not a one line way but is the closest to that.

after having your cert files you need to run this:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create test-ingress-1 \ --certificate [FIRST_CERT_FILE] --private-key [FIRST_KEY_FILE]
```

then you need to create your YAML file with the configuration (in the link there are two examples)

run this command:

```
kubectl apply -f [NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE].yaml
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl